# Fancybox, only refresh parent page after submit, but not on close

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

I have a Fancybox form (iframe).  When the user submits the form, I am having it refresh the parent page. But if the user decided to close the Fancybox form without submitting, the refresh of the parent page is still happening.

this is my fancy box code:

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".edit_product").fancybox({
        autoScale   : true,
        fitToView   : false,
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        title       : '',
        type        : 'iframe', 
        afterClose  : function () {
                parent.location.reload(true);
        }               
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the submit code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> //EDIT PRODUCT
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        target:        '',
        dataType:      'html',          
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest_editprod,        
        success:       showResponse_editprod
    }; 

    $(".edit_product_div").delegate("#edit_product_form","submit",function () {
        $("#edit_product_loading").show(500);
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
        return false;
    });

});
function showRequest_editprod(formData, jqForm, options){
    return true; 
}
function showResponse_editprod(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form){       
    parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
}
</script>
```

Is there a way to only refresh the parent page after a submit, and if the user clicks on the "x" or outside of the Fancybox, it just closes the fancy box without refreshing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the reload line :

```
afterClose  : function () {
                parent.location.reload(true);
        }
```

`parent.location.reload` will load the page again.

Add reload code to success function like this

```
function showResponse_editprod(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form){    
    parent.location.reload(true);
}
```

Comment: Removing the line will also stop the parent page from reloading after the form submit.

Comment: you can write this code within `submit` function not `onclose`.

Comment: Remove reload code from close function and add to success like i did.Try and update me about the result.

Comment: I removed the the code from afterClose and added what you posted to the showResponse function and the parent page still does not reload after submit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44584/discussion-between-mahmood-rehman-and-dobotjr)

Comment: YEah sorry didn't work. Tried the edits.  Same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterClose : function() {
        location.reload();
        return;
    }
});
```

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful at point 11

Try it http://jsfiddle.net/EWTxv/